# Is it possible to use ShowDialog without blocking all forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, showdialog

I hope I can explain this clearly enough. I have my main form (A) and it opens 1 child form (B) using form.Show() and a second child form (C) using form.Show(). Now I want child form B to open a form (D) using form.ShowDialog(). When I do this, it blocks form A and form C as well. Is there a way to open a modal dialog and only have it block the form that opened it?

Comment: For info, threading example added

Comment: The question is marked **winforms** but I landed here with somewhat the same problem with **WPF**. For people looking for such kind of information [c-sharp-openfiledialog-non-modal-possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478476/c-sharp-openfiledialog-non-modal-possible)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you run Form B on a separate thread from A and C, the ShowDialog call will only block that thread. Clearly, that's not a trivial investment of work of course.

You can have the dialog not block any threads at all by simply running Form D's ShowDialog call on a separate thread. This requires the same kind of work, but much less of it, as you'll only have one form running off of your app's main thread.

Comment: Jon T - It doesn't have to, but you'd better know what you're doing and hope that there's no interaction between the 2 - sounds like trouble to me.

Comment: I know about invoking between threads and UI threads, I've done quite a bit of that. I was just hoping there was a way to avoid using threading to solve this. It looks like threading might be the only answer though.

Comment: It certainly is trouble, if you don't know what you're doing. But assuming the two don't communicate (or the communication is as simple as reading some data from form D after it closes), it's trivial to implement.

Comment: All UI does not have to run on the same thread, you just need to be sure that you access a form's UI properties on that form's UI thread. So, if A and B are running in different threads, if A accesses B, it will need to do an Invoke. In our app, all forms run on their own threads.

Comment: This is some great information. I knew that you had to use invoke to access UI elements, but I was under the wrong impression that you also had to keep all of those UI elements on the same thread. Running it on a separate thread seems to be the best way to go.

Comment: It should be noted that, while you may be comfortable with multiple UI threads, later maintainers may not be.  Putting this on another UI thread is building in some expensive maintenance if you're not the only dev.

Comment: @Greg D: We're not talking about writing an OS scheduler here; what one needs to know to do this is probably the minimal amount every desktop app programmer should already know about threading.

Comment: examples could have been nice.

Answer (score 113):

Using multiple GUI threads is tricky business, and I would advise against it, if this is your only motivation for doing so.

A much more suitable approach is to use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`, and disable the owner form until the popup form returns.  There are just four considerations:

1. When `ShowDialog(owner)` is used, the popup form stays on top of its owner.  The same is true when you use `Show(owner)`.  Alternatively, you can set the `Owner` property explicitly, with the same effect.
2. If you set the owner form's `Enabled` property to `false`, the form shows a disabled state (child controls are "grayed out"), whereas when `ShowDialog` is used, the owner form still gets disabled, but doesn't show a disabled state.

   When you call `ShowDialog`, the owner form gets disabled in Win32 code—its `WS_DISABLED` style bit gets set.  This causes it to lose the ability to gain the focus and to "ding" when clicked, but doesn't make it draw itself gray.

   When you set a form's `Enabled` property to `false`, an additional flag is set (in the framework, not the underlying Win32 subsystem) that certain controls check when they draw themselves.  This flag is what tells controls to draw themselves in a disabled state.

   So to emulate what would happen with `ShowDialog`, we should set the native `WS_DISABLED` style bit directly, instead of setting the form's `Enabled` property to `false`.  This is accomplished with a tiny bit of interop:

   ```
   const int GWL_STYLE   = -16;
   const int WS_DISABLED = 0x08000000;

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

   void SetNativeEnabled(bool enabled){
       SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_STYLE) &
           ~WS_DISABLED | (enabled ? 0 : WS_DISABLED));
   }
   ```
3. The `ShowDialog()` call doesn't return until the dialog is dismissed.  This is handy, because you can suspend the logic in your owner form until the dialog has done its business.  The `Show()` call, necessarily, does not behave this way.  Therefore, if you're going to use `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`, you'll need to break your logic into two parts.  The code that should run after the dialog is dismissed (which would include re-enabling the owner form), should be run by a `Closed` event handler.
4. When a form is shown as a dialog, setting its `DialogResult` property automatically closes it.  This property gets set whenever a button with a `DialogResult` property other than `None` is clicked.  A form shown with `Show` will not automatically close like this, so we must explicitly close it when one of its dismissal buttons is clicked.  Note, however, that the `DialogResult` property still gets set appropriately by the button.

Implementing these four things, your code becomes something like:

```
class FormB : Form{
    void Foo(){
        SetNativeEnabled(false); // defined above
        FormD f = new FormD();
        f.Closed += (s, e)=>{
            switch(f.DialogResult){
            case DialogResult.OK:
                // Do OK logic
                break;
            case DialogResult.Cancel:
                // Do Cancel logic
                break;
            }
            SetNativeEnabled(true);
        };
        f.Show(this);
        // function Foo returns now, as soon as FormD is shown
    }
}

class FormD : Form{
    public FormD(){
        Button btnOK       = new Button();
        btnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        btnOK.Text         = "OK";
        btnOK.Click       += (s, e)=>Close();
        btnOK.Parent       = this;

        Button btnCancel       = new Button();
        btnCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        btnCancel.Text         = "Cancel";
        btnCancel.Click       += (s, e)=>Close();
        btnCancel.Parent       = this;

        AcceptButton = btnOK;
        CancelButton = btnCancel;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 a much more complete answer than mine - but essentially the same approach! Will get rid of mine as yours is so much more complete.

Comment: When you open a form with ShowDialog() and then try to click on a parent form, the child form is flashing and a ding sound is played. But with your code, it doesn't happen, i.e. you can't focus a parent form, yes, but the child form is not flashing and no sound is played. So the new behavior is confusing to a user.

Comment: @nightcoder:  I know it's been a year, but I just noticed your comment.  The sample I give above does indeed cause the foreground form (FormD) to flash and the ding sound is played.  Perhaps in your code, you haven't set the owner property on FormD (in my sample, that's done by passing `this` to `f.Show()`, but you could also set `f.Owner = this`).  This is necessary for the owned window to flash.  Even without that, it should ding, though, and it does for me.

Comment: @p-daddy: Thanks for this bit of code. It was helpful in implementing a similar solution for my needs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16088711/654244

Comment: I implemented this solution and it worked great.  Thank you.  I will add though that my form would still came to the top of all other of the app's forms if the parent wasn't currently active.  Which is not what I wanted.  So I fired this only if `ActiveForm` was the parent form.  If not then I set a property on the parent form itself to open the form in the parent form's `Activated` event.

Comment: I know this is super old, but instead of using GetWindowLong/SetWindowLong you can just use [EnableWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnableWindow.html).

Comment: Pay attention to also disable all other windows of the application – except your foreground dialog. And activate the owner window after re-enabling it or it will lose focus (at least in WPF it does).

Answer (score 13):

You can use a separate thread (as below), but this is getting into dangerous territory - you should only go near this option if you understand the implications of threading (synchronization, cross-thread access, etc.):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Button loadB, loadC;
    Form formA = new Form {
        Text = "Form A",
        Controls = {
            (loadC = new Button { Text = "Load C", Dock = DockStyle.Top}),
            (loadB = new Button { Text = "Load B", Dock = DockStyle.Top})
        }
    };
    loadC.Click += delegate {
        Form formC = new Form { Text = "Form C" };
        formC.Show(formA);
    };
    loadB.Click += delegate {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
            Button loadD;
            Form formB = new Form {
                Text = "Form B",
                Controls = {
                    (loadD = new Button { Text = "Load D",
                        Dock = DockStyle.Top})
                }
            };
            loadD.Click += delegate {
                Form formD = new Form { Text = "Form D"};
                formD.ShowDialog(formB);
            };
            formB.ShowDialog();  // No owner; ShowDialog to prevent exit
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    };
    Application.Run(formA);
}
```

(Obviously, you wouldn't actually structure the code like the above - this is just the shortest way of showing the behavior; in real code you'd have a class per form, etc.)

Comment: Excellent example - thanks. I've decided to go down the threaded road, as it seems like the best option.

Answer (score 12):

I would like to summarize possible solutions and add one new alternatives (3a and 3b). But first I want to clarify what we are talking about:

*We have an application which have multiple forms. There is a requirement to show modal dialog which would block only certain subset of our forms but not the others. Modal dialogs may be shown only in one subset (scenario A) or multiple subsets (scenario B).*

And now summary of possible solutions:

1. **Don't use modal forms shown via `ShowDialog()` at all**

   Think about design of your application. Do you really need to use `ShowDialog()` method? If you don't need having modal form it's the easiest and the cleanest way to go.

   Of course this solution is not always suitable. There are some features which `ShowDialog()` gives us. The most notable is that it disables the owner (but do not grays out) and user cannot interact with it. The very exhausting answer provided [P Daddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428782/2870889).
2. **Emulate `ShowDialog()` behavior**

   It is possible to emulate behavior of that mathod. Again I recommend reading [P Daddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428782/2870889).

   **a) Use** combination of **`Enabled` property on `Form`** and showing form as non-modal via `Show()`. As a result disabled form will be grayed out. But it's completely managed solution without any interop needed.

   **b)** Don't like the parent form being grayed out? Reference few native methods and **turn off `WS_DISABLED` bit on parent form** (once again - see answer from [P Daddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428782/2870889)).

   Those two solutions require that you have complete control on all the dialog boxes you need to handle. You have to use special construct to show "partially blocking dialog" and must not forget about it. You need to adjust your logic because `Show()` is non-blocking and `ShowDialog()` is blocking. Dealing with system dialogs (file choosers, color pickers, etc.) could be problem. On the other hand you do not need any extra code on the forms which shall not be blocked by dialog.
3. **Overcome limitations of `ShowDialog()`**

   Note that there are [`Application.EnterThreadModal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enterthreadmodal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Application.LeaveThreadModal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.leavethreadmodal(v=vs.110).aspx) events. This event is raised whenever modal dialog is shown. Beware that events are actually thread-wide, not application-wide.

   **a) Listen to the `Application.EnterThreadModal` event** in forms which shall not be blocked by dialog and **turn on `WS_DISABLED` bit** in those forms. You only need to adjust forms which should not be blocked by modal dialogs. You may also need to inspect the parent-chain of the modal form being shown and switch `WS_DISABLED` based on this condition (in your example if you also needed to open dialogs by forms A and C but not to block forms B and D).

   **b) Hide and re-show forms which should not be blocked**. Note that when you show new form after modal dialog is shown it is not blocked. Take advantage of that and when modal dialog is shown, hide and show again desired forms so that they are not blocked. However this approach may bring some flickering. It could be theoretically fixed by enabling/disabling repaint of forms in Win API but I do not guarantee that.

   **c) Set `Owner` property to dialog form** on forms which should not be blocked when dialog is shown. I did not test this.

   **d) Use multiple GUI threads**. [Answer from TheSmurf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428517/2870889).

Comment: Very nice. I think this should be the best answer.

Answer (score 6):

Start FormB in a new thread in FormA:

```
        (new System.Threading.Thread(()=> {
            (new FormB()).Show();
        })).Start();
```

Now, any forms opened in the new thread using ShowDialog() will only block FormB and NOT FormA or FormC

Comment: This opens form and it closes immediately

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to add my solution here as it seems to work well for me, and can be encapsulated into a simple extension method. The only thing I need to do is deal with the flashing as @nightcoder commented on @PDaddy's answer.

```
public static void ShowWithParentFormLock(this Form childForm, Form parentForm)
{
  childForm.ShowWithParentFormLock(parentForm, null);
}

public static void ShowWithParentFormLock(this Form childForm, Form parentForm, Action actionAfterClose)
{
  if (childForm == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("childForm");
  if (parentForm == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("parentForm");
  EventHandler activatedDelegate = (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
  {
    childForm.Focus();
    //To Do: Add ability to flash form to notify user that focus changed
  };
  childForm.FormClosed += (sender, closedEventArgs) =>
    {
      try
      {
        parentForm.Focus();
        if(actionAfterClose != null)
          actionAfterClose();
      }
      finally
      {
        try
        {
          parentForm.Activated -= activatedDelegate;
          if (!childForm.IsDisposed || !childForm.Disposing)
            childForm.Dispose();
        }
        catch { }
      }
    };
  parentForm.Activated += activatedDelegate;
  childForm.Show(parentForm);
}
```

Comment: @Anne I think you forgot to actually click the +1 :)

Comment: It turnes out, the only thing you need to make a child form flash when one tries to select a parent form is to add `parentForm.Enabled = false;` before `childForm.Show(parentForm);`. Just don't forget to add `parentForm.Enabled = true;` before or after `parentForm.Focus();`. @JustinPihony, thanks for your solution, simple and effective.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing a similar problem in an application I was writing. My main UI was a form running on the main thread. I had a help dialog that I wanted to run as a modeless dialog. This was easy to implement, even to the point of ensuring that I only ever had one instance of the help dialog running. Unfortunately, any modal dialogs I used caused the help dialog to lose focus as well - when it was while some of these modal dialogs were running that having the help dialog there would be most useful.

Using ideas mentioned here, and in other places, I managed to overcome this bug.

I declared a thread inside my main UI.

```
Thread helpThread;
```

The following code deals with the event fired to open the help dialog.

```
private void Help(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if help dialog is still open then thread is still running
    //if not, we need to recreate the thread and start it again
    if (helpThread.ThreadState != ThreadState.Running)
    {
        helpThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startHelpThread));
        helpThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        helpThread.Start();
    }
}

void startHelpThread()
{
    using (HelpDialog newHelp = new HelpDialog(resources))
    {
        newHelp.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

I also needed the initialization of the thread added into my constructor to make sure that I was not referencing a null object the first time this code is run.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    ...
    helpThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startHelpThread));
    helpThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    ...
}
```

This makes sure that the thread has only one instance at any given time. The thread itself runs the dialog, and stops once the dialog is closed. Since it runs on a separate thread, creating a modal dialog from within the main UI does not cause the help dialog to hang. I did need to add

```
helpDialog.Abort();
```

to the form closing event of my main UI to make sure that the help dialog closes when the application is terminated.

I now have a modeless help dialog which is not affected by any modal dialogs spawned from within my main UI, which is exactly what I wanted. This is safe since there is no communication needed between the main UI and the help dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Here is helper I'm using in WPF to prevent dialog from blocking non dialog windows based on some answers to this question:

```
public static class WindowHelper
{
    public static bool? ShowDialogNonBlocking(this Window window)
    {
        var frame = new DispatcherFrame();

        void closeHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            frame.Continue = false;
        }

        try
        {
            window.Owner.SetNativeEnabled(false);
            window.Closed += closeHandler;
            window.Show();

            Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
        }
        finally
        {
            window.Closed -= closeHandler;
            window.Owner.SetNativeEnabled(true);
        }
        return window.DialogResult;
    }

    const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    const int WS_DISABLED = 0x08000000;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    static void SetNativeEnabled(this Window window, bool enabled)
    {
        var handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
        SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE) &
            ~WS_DISABLED | (enabled ? 0 : WS_DISABLED));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if(true == window.ShowDialogNonBlocking())
{
    // Dialog result has correct value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a child window (see *[ChildWindow](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow&referringTitle=Home)* for details) would be a more elegant solution, and it would avoid all the problems with separate threads for the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Using Example:

```
(new NoneBlockingDialog((new frmDialog()))).ShowDialogNoneBlock(this);
```

Source code:

```
class NoneBlockingDialog
{
    Form dialog;
    Form Owner;

    public NoneBlockingDialog(Form f)
    {
        this.dialog = f;
        this.dialog.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(f_FormClosing);
    }

    void f_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if(! e.Cancel)
            PUtils.SetNativeEnabled(this.Owner.Handle, true);
    }

    public void ShowDialogNoneBlock(Form owner)
    {
        this.Owner = owner;
        PUtils.SetNativeEnabled(owner.Handle, false);
        this.dialog.Show(owner);
    }
}

partial class PUtils
{
            const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    const int WS_DISABLED = 0x08000000;


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);


    static public void SetNativeEnabled(IntPtr hWnd, bool enabled)
    {
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_DISABLED | (enabled ? 0 : WS_DISABLED));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to this thread looking to do something similar: have multiple independent parent forms, running in the same process, each with their own modal dialog. An analogy, which I planned to use as proof of it being possible, would be multiple Word documents, each with their own Find-and-Replace window.

I was sure I'd done this before, but upon trying it, well what do you know, **even Microsoft Word can't do this**. It behaves exactly as the OP described: once you open a modal dialog (like Find and Replace using Ctrl+H), ALL Word documents become blocked and can't be interacted with.
Worse still, only clicking the original parent document causes the modal dialog to flash. The rest of them just don't respond, and give no hint as to why they're blocked or what needs to be closed.

This could indeed be a very confusing user experience. I find it surprising that this is the case with Microsoft's own flagship office software (and that I haven't noticed it before). However, it also helped me come to terms with my own application behaving the same way.

Further confirmation comes from the [.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#remarks) itself, which states that "`ShowDialog` shows the window, disables all other windows ***in the application***, and returns only when the window is closed."

---

I realize this isn't technically a "solution". Those who really feel their application needs to support fully-independent parent forms can try the [workaround by @PDaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428782/2299915), which seems very thorough.

However, hopefully this gives a little peace of mind to those who (like me) were just trying to be conscientious with their UI and thought they were doing something wrong. You're not crazy. Apparently, this is just how Windows works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for `Form.ShowDialog(ownern)` and `FileOpenDialog.ShowDialog(owner)` and `MessageBox.Show(text)`.

**The advantage of this solution is: The `ShowDialog(owner)` will wait until the user closed the dialog, but the other forms of your app are still usable furthermore, and it's very easy to implement for all of your `ShowDialog(owner)` calls.**

You just need to add `using (new ModalDialogService())` immediately before your `ShowDialog(owner)` usage:

```
using (new ModalDialogService(this))
    new Form1().ShowDialog(this);

using (new ModalDialogService(this))
    new FileOpenDialog().ShowDialog(this);

using (new ModalDialogService(this))
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
```

You can store the `ModalDialogService.cs` somewhere in your project.

The implementation of it is:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ModalDialogService : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IWin32Window _owner;
        private readonly HookProc _hookProc;
        private nint _hHook = 0;
        private readonly WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext = new();

        public ModalDialogService(Form owner)
        {
            if (owner == null) 
                return;

            _owner = owner;
            _hookProc = DialogHookProc;

            _hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROCRET, _hookProc, 0, GetCurrentThreadId());
        }

        private nint DialogHookProc(int nCode, nint wParam, nint lParam)
        {
            if (nCode < 0)
                return CallNextHookEx(_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

            var hook = _hHook;

            if (Marshal.PtrToStructure<CWPRETSTRUCT>(lParam).message == HCBT_ACTIVATE)
            {
                _synchronizationContext.Post(
                    (state) =>
                    {
                        foreach (var openForm in Application.OpenForms)
                            if (openForm is Form form
                                && form != _owner
                                && form.IsHandleCreated)
                            {
                                nint handle = 0;
                                form.Invoke(() => handle = form.Handle); // Make sure, to get the Handle on the form thread

                                EnableWindow(handle, true);
                                var timer = new System.Timers.Timer()
                                {
                                    Interval = 100,
                                };
                                timer.Elapsed +=
                                    (sender, e) =>
                                    {
                                        timer.Dispose();
                                        _ = SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_DISABLED);
                                    };
                            }
                    },
                    null);

                _ = UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hHook);
                _hHook = 0;
            };

            return CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_hHook != 0)
                _ = UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hHook);

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public delegate nint HookProc(int nCode, nint wParam, nint lParam);

        private const int WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12;
        private const int HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern nint SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, nint hInstance, int threadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(nint idHook);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern nint CallNextHookEx(nint idHook, int nCode, nint wParam, nint lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool EnableWindow(nint hWnd, bool bEnable);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct CWPRETSTRUCT
        {
            public nint lResult;
            public nint lParam;
            public nint wParam;
            public uint message;
            public nint hwnd;
        };

        const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        const int WS_DISABLED = 0x08000000;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowLong(nint hWnd, int nIndex);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(nint hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
    }
}
```