# Is it possible to use ShowDialog from MdiChildForm without blocking all others MdiChildForms and MdiParent?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdichild, showdialog, mdiparent

I need to open modal form (frmD) from MdiChild (frmB) form without blocking main form (frmA) and all others opened MdiChild forms (frmC). Then i switch to frmC the frmD is hidden.

[This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428494/is-it-possible-to-use-showdialog-without-blocking-all-forms) the similar question, but not for Mdi application.

Is there a way to open a modal dialog and only have it block the mdi child form that opened it?

Comment: you missed the link "This is".. correct it

Comment: What was wrong with using the `Show` method (rather than `ShowDialog`) and setting the MDI child form's `WS_DISABLED` style flag using P/Invoke, as suggested by [P Daddy's excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428494/is-it-possible-to-use-showdialog-without-blocking-all-forms/428782#428782) to the "similar question"?

Comment: And what should the MDI commands Cascade, Tile and Minimize-All do when your dialog is up?

Comment: Cody Gray, in principle suitable...1) how can i positioning the modal forms only at center of its disabled parent? 2) how to set focus to modal after clicking on its parent?

Comment: Henk Holterman, mdi layouts work correct

Answer (score 0):

One possible strategy is described in [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/1358e4e8-ae3d-4170-abc0-04a89f349a56), which relies on using the `.Show()` method instead of `.ShowDialog()` to open the modal dialog and setting the MdiChild's `Enabled` property to false just before you call the `.Show()` method.

You then need to set the `Enabled` property of your MdiChild back to true when the dialog is closed, which means that you will need to create an event handler in your MdiChild form to handle the `FormClosing` event of the dialog.

Comment: The problem with simply setting the child form's `Enabled` property to false is that all of its controls will take on a disabled appearance (that is, they will look grayed out). Considering that's not how modal dialogs behave in Windows, your application is going to be confusing to users. But there's a better solution that I already suggested in a comment; see [P Daddy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428494/is-it-possible-to-use-showdialog-without-blocking-all-forms/428782#428782) to the question linked to by the OP.

Comment: You make a valid point - the answer given by @P Daddy is very comprehensive.