# C# WinForms: How to set Main function STAThreadAttribute

Tags: c#, winforms

I get the following exception when calling `saveFileDialog.ShowDialog()` in a background thread:

> Current thread must be set to single
>   thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE
>   calls can be made. Ensure that your
>   Main function has STAThreadAttribute
>   marked on it.

According to [this](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pwcs/ThreadStateException.html):

> To fix the problem, insert the
>   statement:

```
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState = Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
```

> in Main right before the
>   Application.Run statement.

But the Application.Run statement is in Program.cs which seems to be generated code so any changes might be unexpectedly lost. Also, I could not find a way to set current thread to STA in the project or main form properties but maybe I am looking in the wrong place.
What is the proper way to call `saveFileDialog.ShowDialog()` in a background thread?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428494/is-it-possible-to-use-showdialog-without-blocking-all-forms

Comment: [Don't do UI in a background thread.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/18/5501378.aspx)

Comment: Program.cs is created by the wizard, but never regenerated (unlike *.Designer.cs, etc, where your changes really would be lost).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

ShowDialog() shouldn't be called from a background thread - use Invoke(..).

```
Invoke((Action)(() => { saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() }));
```

Comment: Nathan, YDM! After 10 years - thanks. The error message was so misleading.

Answer (score 58):

Solution very easy;
Just add this on top of the Main method  `[STAThread]`

So your main method should look like this

```
 [STAThread]
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     ....
 }
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 14):

this should work if you are creating the thread in which you call the showDialog:

```
var thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(param => { saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(); }));
 thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 7):

Add following code on `FormLoad`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread myth;
    myth = new Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(CallSaveDialog)); 
    myth.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
    myth.Start();
}
```

Here `CallSaveDialog` is a thread and here you can call `ShowDialog` like this

```
void CallSaveDialog(){saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();}
```

Comment: +1, only one solution that worked for me (calling `ShowDialog()` from another thread in my .dll). Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add some explanation on what this does?

Answer (score 1):

On your MainForm:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired) { 
 this.Invoke(saveFileDialog.ShowDialog()); 
} else { 
 saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(); 
}
```

Or, if you will have other methods that need to be run from the UI thread:

```
  private void DoOnUIThread(MethodInvoker d) {
     if (this.InvokeRequired) { this.Invoke(d); } else { d(); }
  }
```

Then, call your method as such:

```
 DoOnUIThread(delegate() {
    saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
 });
```