# Not able to update email body in Meeting Request

Tags: vba, outlook, meeting-request

I am not able to create a meeting request. I get an error on .HTMLbody line. The error which I receive is "Run time error '438' Object does not support this property or method" . I have also added RangeToHTML code from Ron De'Bruin.

Please assist me with the request.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Meeting_Request()
Dim myoutlook As Object ' Outlook.Application
Dim r As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim myapt As Object ' Outlook.AppointmentItem

' late bound constants
Const olAppointmentItem = 1
Const olBusy = 2
Const olMeeting = 1

' Create the Outlook session
Set myoutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Start at row 18
Sheets("Automation").Select
r = 18

Do Until Trim$(Cells(r, 1).Value) = ""
'Adding Goals and other details in email draft


Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Range("A9:A14").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With




'Sheets("Automation").Select
' Create the AppointmentItem

Set myapt = myoutlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
' Set the appointment properties
'Sheets("Automation").Select
With myapt
  .Subject = Sheets("Automation").Range("N" & r) & " day review"
  .Start = Sheets("Automation").Range("P" & r) & " " & "7:00:00 PM"
  .Duration = 0
  .Recipients.Add Sheets("Automation").Range("C" & r).Value & ";" & Sheets("Automation").Range("K" & r).Value
  .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
  ' not necessary if recipients are email addresses
  ' myapt.Recipients.ResolveAll
  '.AllDayEvent = "No"
    .BusyStatus = olBusy
   ' .BusyStatus = Cells(r, 5).Value
    .ReminderSet = False
  .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
  .Save
  r = r + 1
  .Display
End With

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: '438' Object does not support this property or method" = AppointmentItem does not support `HTMLBody`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/appointmentitem-object-outlook Use `.body` or `.RTFBody`.

Answer (score 1):

Appointment items use the RTF markup for bodies instead of HTML (see the [RTFBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861303.aspx) property). So, you will not find the `HTMLBody` property for appointments. You can use the Word object model if you need to paste some HTML markup to the body. See [Write HTML content to word document using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064231/write-html-content-to-word-document-using-c-sharp) for more information.

Starting from Outlook 2016 you can try to access the `PR_HTML` property which represents the HTML body using AppointmentItem.PropertyAccessor. The DASL name is http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10130102.