# C# Show Dialog threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, dialog, showdialog

I have a `Dialog Box` (Importer) which i use for choosing a file I want to import into an app. This `Dialog Box` (Importer) also has another Dialog Box (File) which is an `OpenFileDialog`.

The code runs something like this

```
//Main File

if (Importer.ShowDialog == DialogResult.Ok){
// Start Import
}

//Importer File

OnDoubleClick of TextBox

if(File.ShowDialog == DialogResult.Ok){
// Find File
}
```

However on the Second `ShowDialog` I always get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.
```

Is this a threading issue, and how should i deal with it.

I look forward to hearing from you.
Regards
James

--Update some more code to help This is all inside the first Form.ShowDialog()

```
private void fileNametxt_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        myth = new Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ChooseFile));
        myth.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
        myth.Start();

        while(myth.ThreadState != ThreadState.Aborted || myth.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped)
        {
               fileNametxt.Text = FileName;
        }

        fileNametxt.Text = FileName;


    }


    private void ChooseFile()
    {
        openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (openFileDialog.FileName != "")
        {
            FileName = openFileDialog.FileName.Trim();

        }

        myth.Abort();

    }
```

How do I stop the thread and update the text on screen. The thread only seems to be able to talk to varibles not UI controls.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373645/c-sharp-winforms-how-to-set-main-function-stathreadattribute) out.

Comment: Is the dialog being shown from the main thread?

Comment: Programmers have a knack for doing this backwards.  The *right* way of doing this is to display the dialog on the UI thread and to run the importing code on a worker thread.  Doing it the other way around is always wrong and produces runtime exceptions like this one.  And a wholelottamore trouble.  Use BackgroundWorker or the Task class to run the importer.

Comment: you should include the rest of your code too. This does not give enough clues to understand what is causing the cross threading problem.

Comment: Why did you choose to show the dialog away from the main thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix it mark your `Main()` method of `Program` class with attribute `[STAThread]`.

Follow-up reading: [CA2232: Mark Windows Forms entry points with STAThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182351.aspx).

In this case of course `Main()` method **is** your entry point regardless of what framework does.

Comment: hi @Migol, do you know how it goes with web forms?

Answer (score 0):

In this error. Build solution is not raise error but debug raise that error.
I try create new solution and add exciting item to new solution. The error has fixed!