# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException error (C#)

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get an information from the web (`adress` in my code) with HtmlAgilityPack in C#, but I have to wait until the `<div class="center fs22 green lh32">` is loaded on the page.

When I execute this code :

```
    var url = $"https://www.website.com/";
    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = web.LoadFromBrowser(url, html =>
    {
        return !html.Contains("<div class=\"center fs22 green lh32\"></div>");
    });
    string adress = doc.DocumentNode
          .SelectSingleNode("//td/span[@id='testedAddress")
          .Attributes["value"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Voici l'adresse :",adress);
```

I always get this error :

[image: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException]

[image: ThreadStateException: Impossible d'instancier le contrôle ActiveX '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2', car le thread actuel n'est pas un thread cloisonné (STA, Single-Threaded Apartment).]

**Translation :**  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'An exception has been raised by the target of an appeal.'

> ThreadStateException: Can not instantiate ActiveX control 
>   '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2', because the current thread is
>   not a partitioned thread (STA, Single-Threaded Apartment).

How can I get rid of this error ?

Comment: Are you by any chance running this code in a separate Thread?

Comment: No, all my code is in one thread

Comment: That's odd, usually this only happens when you try to use UI components in a non STA-Thread.

Comment: Try setting the thread apartment to STA in your Main() [STAThread]

Comment: @Lulucmy Is this a console application?

Comment: Yes a console app

and @Oscar I don't know how to do that...

Comment: @Lulucmy https://stackoverflow.com/a/13825951/3214843

Comment: @Lulucmy if that solves you problem, please accept Oscars answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply STAThreadAttribute to your Main function:

```
 [STAThread]
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     //Your code here
 }
```