# C# - Run Task in foreach listviewitem with xNet Request

Tags: c#, winforms

My Code :

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in list.Items)
        {
            string url, path, host;
            url = item.SubItems[0].Text; // example "www.google.com/"
            path =  item.SubItems[1].Text; // example = "login/"
            host = (item.SubItems[2].Text); // example = "123.123.123:232";
            bool ping = Request(url, path, host);
            if (ping) {
            item.Subitems[3].Text = "This is good";
            } else {
            item.Subitems[3].Text = "This is bad";
            }
        }
```

and this is the Request Method

```
public bool Request(string url, string path, string host)
    {
        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
        //a lot if code with httpRequest 
        if (result == "good")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

so this code dose not have any error when i put like 20 item in list and run this code its close the application so i have to add Task to make it run without close the app .

so i do this

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in list.Items)
        {
         await Task.Run(() => {
            string url, path, host;
            url = item.SubItems[0].Text; // example "www.google.com/"
            path =  item.SubItems[1].Text; // example = "login/"
            host = (item.SubItems[2].Text); // example = "123.123.123:232";
            bool ping = Request(url, path, host);
            if (ping) {
            item.Subitems[3].Text = "This is good";
            } else {
            item.Subitems[3].Text = "This is bad";
            }
          }
        }
```

but its give me this error
**Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA)**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# WinForms: How to set Main function STAThreadAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373645/c-sharp-winforms-how-to-set-main-function-stathreadattribute)

Comment: Sorry, but why do you need to add a Task in order to prevent application exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access UI elements from a background thread (i.e., code running in a `Task.Run`).

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in list.Items)
{
  string url, path, host;
  url = item.SubItems[0].Text; // example "www.google.com/"
  path =  item.SubItems[1].Text; // example = "login/"
  host = (item.SubItems[2].Text); // example = "123.123.123:232";

  var result = await Task.Run(() => {
    bool ping = Request(url, path, host);
    if (ping) {
      return "This is good";
    } else {
      return "This is bad";
    }
  });
  item.Subitems[3].Text = result;
}
```

Comment: after i look to my code i found i use Clipboard.setText() . and i remove it but still the give me error so i use your code and its work thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

You can't change UI Content, when you're not calling it from the UI Thread. In order to do so from another Thread you need to Invoke your method from the Forms dispatcher like this:

```cs
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
{ 
      if (ping) {
         item.Subitems[3].Text = "This is good";
      } else {
         item.Subitems[3].Text = "This is bad";
      }
}));

//**this** is the form you want to update
```

Also check this Question which covers the problem too:
[Invoke in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650691/invoke-in-windows-forms)

Comment: i have tried this and its also give the same error .

Comment: Make sure you use this on every Line of code that accesses the UI