# wpf - window freezes

Tags: wpf, xaml, window

Parent window freezes when I open a window on click of a button. It works properly again if I minimize and maximize parent window again.

System configuration

- Windows 7, 64 bit OS.
- .Net framework 3.5 SP1
- Visual studio express 2008

Following is the simple application where I can reproduce this issue.

Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Width="200"/>
    <Button Content="click" Click="Button_Click"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Window1.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1 {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window1 : Window {
    public Window1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        (new Window2()).ShowDialog();
    }
}
}
```

Window2.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

It works fine if I remove **WindowStyle="ToolWindow"**  !!!!!!

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to `ShowDialog()` is blocking your GUI thread.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428494/is-it-possible-to-use-showdialog-without-blocking-all-forms) for alternative approaches which don't block the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Show` instead of `ShowDialog` which opens a window in Modal mode

Answer (score 1):

If you use ShowDialog() try set Window1 as Owner for Window2:

```
        Window2 w = new Window2 { Owner = this };
        w.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Show instead of show dialog will work, but maybe you intention was something more like a child window see http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow&referringTitle=Home for details.