# How to change the property show of Form.showDialog to show

Tags: c#, winforms

I have already opened my `Form` with `showdialog()`. I want to have the possibility to change (or set) the property of `modal` for this form, without showing again this form by `show`.

Comment: I would give this thread a read : http://stackoverflow.com/a/428782/3922214

Comment: And why is showing the form again a problem?

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to solve the wrong problem.  Have the dialog form raise an event that the calling form is listening for, then it can run whatever code you need to have run.  Otherwise, it's pretty unclear why you want to change a modal form to a non-modal form *while it's being displayed*.

Comment: Can you say what's the original problem which you are trying to solve? It seems to be [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).