# Can I subscribe to an event somewhere in wpf to listen for showDialog or new windows?

Tags: wpf

I want to observe certain information about all windows in my app. I have a window that shows (via Observables) lots of information, but I can't find anything short of polling that will let me know all the windows (and also all open windows in my app).

Is there somewhere I can subscribe that would be a good hook for any windows getting shown (`.Show()` or `.ShowDialog()`) ?

Comment: A modal dialog blocks interaction events to its *parent* window. In a test just now, I was able to create a parent window which *non-modally* showed a non-child window. `public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); (new TestWindow()).Show(); }`. When `MainWindow` was showing a modal child (`MessageBox` will do), the `TestWindow` continued to respond to user input, because it wasn't a child of the main window. If your first paragraph is all you really care about and the rest is just a hypothetical way of doing that, it's easy.

Comment: ...that is, unless you mean you want your main window to be responsive while there's a modal child. That's easy too: Just don't make the children modal. If all you want from `ShowDialog()` is for the child to stay on top, there are other ways to do that.

Comment: I've got the app.xaml.cs calling show on the window, without setting a child, and still, when a modal dialog comes up, the dump live window won't let me click it to look at the diag info. I want all the modals to behave as they would otherwise in the app. but this one to ignore any/all modals. Which opening this window, as a non-child is not helping with for some reason. your sample case looks like it should work for me.

Comment: If it doesn't work, I guess you're probably doing something different. Can't guess what.

Comment: @Maslow, when I had a similar problem in WinForms (more than one modal dialog in developers environment), I used an approach suggested by Marc Gravell here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/428556/1506454 for [is-it-possible-to-use-showdialog-without-blocking-all-forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428494/is-it-possible-to-use-showdialog-without-blocking-all-forms). Haven't yet tried for wpf windows :\. using `window.Show()` as suggested above doesn't for me: window is blocked by another modal dialog

Comment: Are you maybe blocking on the UI thread (assuming there's only one)? That'd shut down everything for user input.

Comment: @Maslow Lets start one by one. Your question title, and question description saying two diff things. I am working on your problem. Please tell your first requirement.

Comment: @Maslow As far as I understood your problem, you want one single CommonWindow to become child of unlimited Modal windows, and if current modal window is closed, CommonWindow should become child of next latest modal window ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan yes

Comment: @Maslow Please check if my answer suits your needs.

Comment: I need to edit the question to focus more on what I want to know, can I listen/subscribe to an event anywhere that will tell me when new windows have a `.Show()` or `.ShowDialog()` call made inside my app

Answer (score 0):

You have to add references to `UIAutomationClient.dll`, `UIAutomationTypes.dll`.

On my machine, they are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5`.

`CommonWindow` is used as your common window, which keeps changing its owner. I create modal windows, which can further create more modal windows, and latest one ***owns*** `CommonWindow`, I also set latest window as `DataContext` of `CommonWindow`.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        CommonWindow _commonWin = new CommonWindow();

        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {            
            Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
                   WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
                   AutomationElement.RootElement,
                   TreeScope.Children,
                   (s, e1) =>
                   {
                       Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                       {
                           var windows = Application.Current.Windows;

                           Window w = windows[windows.Count - 1];
                           w.Closing += w_Closing;

                           // First modal window is shown, so count now is 2 (>1)
                           if (App.Current.Windows.Count > 1)
                           {
                               _commonWin.Owner = w;
                               _commonWin.DataContext = w;
                               _commonWin.Show();
                           }
                       });
                   });
        }

        void w_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            // Comparison to 3 is important as there would be 3 windows when first modal window is shown
            if (Application.Current.Windows.Count >= 3)
            {
                _commonWin.Owner = Application.Current.Windows[App.Current.Windows.Count - 2];
                _commonWin.DataContext = Application.Current.Windows[App.Current.Windows.Count - 2];
            }
            else
            {
                _commonWin.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`CommonWindow` is just a `Window` as `CommonWindow.xaml` just like normal xaml file with its code-behind.

Comment: I have shared my code here https://www.dropbox.com/s/vttmmzf1j4wdvbp/WpfApplication1.rar?dl=0

Comment: well, I'm not entirely happy/comfortable with having a referencing to an automation/testing framework in the main app, but I will give this code a shot. It looks like it may work with a few adjustments

Comment: @Maslow Other approach is to use hooks. I will now work on it, and post that version too.